# How can I send image local to line notify?

Tags: php, jquery, line

I'm not sure whether line notify supports sending images from local.

But I try to read the document and have tried many pictures.

I still cannot.
How to send me a photo file?

I try parameters `imageFile` but not work.

```
 /*-------------line noti----------------------*/
$line_api = 'https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify';
    $access_token = 'token_code';

    $message = 'test';    //text max 1,000 charecter
    $image_thumbnail_url = 'https://dummyimage.com/1024x1024/f598f5/fff.jpg';  // max size 240x240px JPEG
    $image_fullsize_url = 'https://dummyimage.com/1024x1024/844334/fff.jpg'; //max size 1024x1024px JPEG
    $imageFile = 'copy/240.jpg';
    $sticker_package_id = '';  // Package ID sticker
    $sticker_id = '';    // ID sticker

    $message_data = array(
  'imageThumbnail' => $image_thumbnail_url,
  'imageFullsize' => $image_fullsize_url,
  'message' => $message,
  'imageFile' => $imageFile,
  'stickerPackageId' => $sticker_package_id,
  'stickerId' => $sticker_id
    );

    $result = send_notify_message($line_api, $access_token, $message_data);

 echo '<pre>';
     print_r($result);
     echo '</pre>';
}
/*-------------line noti----------------------*/



function send_notify_message($line_api, $access_token, $message_data){
   $headers = array('Method: POST', 'Content-type: multipart/form-data', 'Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token );

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $line_api);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message_data);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   // Check Error
   if(curl_error($ch))
   {
      $return_array = array( 'status' => '000: send fail', 'message' => curl_error($ch) ); 
   }
   else
   {
      $return_array = json_decode($result, true);
   }
   curl_close($ch);
 return $return_array;
}
```

No `imageFile`:

[image: No imageFile]

[image]

How can I send image local to line notify?

Answer (score 0):

```
$imageFile = new CURLFILE('copy/240.jpg');
```

Comment: please consider adding explanations.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_name_with_full_path = 'D:\\xampp\htdocs\linenotify\images\flower.jpg';
$imageFile = curl_file_create($file_name_with_full_path);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$imageFile = '@C:\copy\240.jpg';
```